# htaccess redirection enters redirection loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, modx

I've created a backend using modx which is on a server with the following url:

http://www.server.com/company-name/en/pages/

The live version of the site has a domain that points to the /en/ directory.
so for correct access I have to go to:

http://www.domain.com/en/pages/

But modx still adds the folder "company-name" to everything. Which then points to a page that doesn't exist.

When I make the following in .htaccess the page enters into a redirection loop and errors.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /de/pages/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com/company-name/en/pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.domain\.ch/en/pages/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I make this work correctly? So that the directory "company-name" is never part of the url?

Comment: Jon Lin's answer gets the job done, but wouldn't it be better to fix the problem at the source rather than rewriting every request that comes through your server? It's a bit hard to troubleshoot without more information about your folder and domain structure, but you can start with the site_url setting (in System Settings or `core/config/config.inc.php`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `%{HTTP_HOST}` will **never** look like `domain\.com/company-name/en/pages/`, since the Host field contains no path information, just a hostname. So you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^company-name/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/en/pages/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll need to put the htaccess file and those rules in the **document root** of your `www.server.com` site.